# CodeIgniter : Unable to locate a model?

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

I know many people here have faced this issue, and I've faced it many times and solved it. But this time I tried all I know and what I found on StackOverFlow but nothing worked..

**My situation :**

I have a model called `ClientsManagement.php` in a folder like this :

`application/models/Management/ClientsManagement.php`

I tried doing :

`$this->load->model('Management/ClientsManagement');`

But I'm getting this error :

*Unable to locate the model you have specified: ClientsManagement*

Notice : It's working on windows, but I faced this problem while moving to linux (debian)..

**Notes :**

- I respected the case (linux is case sensitive)
- I have the rewritten mode working very well.
- IT IS WORKING ON WINDOWS !

Answer (score 0):

I would think would be best to do some thing like where it would have **word model** at the end or start of class and file name just so codeigniter can make sure it's model and not any thing else.

**Folder-name:** management => Clients_management_model.php

```
<?php

class Clients_management_model extends CI_Model {
   public function some_function() {
   }
}
```

Then Controller

```
public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('management/clients_management_model');
}

public function index() {
  $data['something'] = $this->clients_management_model->some_function();
}
```

Comment: Something must be wrong with your set up I would think then.

Comment: I tried to start from the beggining, and I could load the model by putting it in model directory, but when I add a directory 'management' it doesn't work. I tried chmod 777 but nothing worked :(

Answer (score 0):

try this 
replace

```
$this->load->model('Management/ClientsManagement');
```

with

```
$this->load->model('Management/ClientsManagement','',true);
```